# Make jquery menu tabs closed by default on load

Tags: jquery

like in the title, I need to have menu tabs closed by default on load.
The code is:

```
$('#cssmenu li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
```

When you change "show" to "hide", it works, but only after the second click...
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a plugin?

Comment: Nope, no plugin, just html, js and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
$('#cssmenu li.active').removeClass('open').children('ul').hide();
```